# why .env file configuration in laravel is not working

Tags: laravel, file, laravel-4, environment-variables

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql      
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1     
DB_PORT=3306     
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=root     
DB_PASSWORD=
```

this is my configuration for laravel 5.4 
but php artisan migrate is not working and have error
and the migrate error

```
Users-MacBook-Pro: ATP Developers php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664: 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table schema = atp_db and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 87:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Please don't post the errors as image, it's unreadable.

Comment: add db name `DB_DATABASE=database_name` and provide password for phpmyadmin `DB_PASSWORD=your_password`

Comment: Have you checked whether there is any password set for your root db? The error is saying that your credential is not correct. That's all.

Comment: thank you but, the credential is ok , it doesn't have any password and the user is root but again has this problem

Comment: Database connection should give and clear config using artiasn

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar problem. So, I run the following commands as mentioned at
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-file-and-config-keys-not-updating-after-change,

`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear`

Also, make sure to restart the server as well

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 2):

you should write these:

```
DB_DATABASE = your database name
DB_USERNAME = root     
DB_PASSWORD = your password
```

and again run `php artisan serve` to make sure about saving `.env` and again run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I had the same problem, I can not explain why Laravel indicates the old Host but the solution is to change the password.

Use below => `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I had this issue after changing my connection password `php artisan config:cache` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change env host entry to `DB_HOST=localhost`. Or add the @'127.0.0.1' credentials to mysql.

Comment: i did (db_host=localhost) but again could not migrate and show this error on the top

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you do not have the correct user and host combination in your database. The env file shows host is 127.0.0.1 but localhost is specified in the error. Add user@localhost entry to the database or user@% for wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

This error would indicate that you don't have a database user configured in your .env file: **''@'localhost'** .  Your .env should have all those fields populated with the database name and credentials you configured before running any function that connects to the database.

Here are the preliminary steps to setup your database and .env file prior to running a php artisan migrate:

Hope it helps.

**Step 1:** Login to your mysql and create the database.

```
mysql -u root -p
create database just_brew_it;
```

**Step 2:** Although you can use root to authenticate via laravel, I'd create a new user to mitigate risk of any security issues:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON just_brew_it.* TO 'brew_user'@'%' identified by 'pint0fStell@' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH privileges;
```

**Step 3:** Modify your .env with the appropriate database, username and password

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql      
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1     
DB_PORT=3306     
DB_DATABASE= just_brew_it
DB_USERNAME= brew_user
DB_PASSWORD= pint0fStell@
```

Comment: thank you very much , though i changed the password to null , again did not worked , and changed db_host to localhost again did not work , i tried all the way but again have the same error

Comment: @Najibjamshidi have you configured your .env file with a database name, username, and password that you have logged into the database with?

Comment: yep i did , the code you have seen is the connection file inside .env but still has problem and can't connect

Comment: Just to be clear, the way your .env file won’t work. I’ve highlighted the steps above to create a database, grant access to a user, then to add that database and new credentials to the database.  It doesn’t sound like you have performed those 3 steps I highlighted. You don’t have a database mapped to the database name, and I assume you are leaving the password empty because you haven’t secured your root account. If you don’t have a database mapped in the field you have empty you will never be able to connect to a database.

Comment: Please send me your .env variables as they are now.

Comment: i did every thing i assigned database name, password to null, user name to root and the all correct , the problem is that this work in windows but as i migrate from win to mac os it does not work , i don't know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163653/discussion-between-najib-jamshidi-and-dom).

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=atp_db 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Ok you missed step two in my answer. Please login to mysql and run that command changing the scheme name, username and password.  Once you assign a password the update the password in your.env file.

Comment: you mean to assign a password for my database ?

Comment: Correct. Assign a password for the user connected to your database.  Typically I run mysql_secure_installation after I install a database so I don’t have the issue you just ran into. I also create a service account for each Laravel instance to ensure a more secure and scalable environment.

Answer (score 0):

This combo worked for me:

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and i couldnt run "config:cache" artisan command even with Artisan::call('config:cache');

so i done this and solved my issue:

artisan config:cache caches all files from /config into a single array that it stores. It then reads all config variables from that array and ignores anything in .env or the /config files until you recache them. That's why it still works after deleting .env.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching

If you don't have ssh access to your live server, you'd just need to delete the bootstrap/cache/config.php file, which is the cache file config:cache generates.